# Elastic Beanstalk with Docker and Persistent Storage

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

we have developed a Java Web-application that I'm currently trying to re-configure to be able to deploy it on docker and at the end put the container on EBS.

Currently the application is running on a bare metal server.

I externalised the App configuration which are environment specific. I'm able to deploy my application on a docker image. The next step is now to put everything on EBS.

The problem I have is, that the application allows users to upload files. The files are currently persisted on the host. With EBS that's a problem for me because I want to run multiple instances for the web tier.

In the future I want to switch from the file-system to S3 which would resolve the problem. But currently I need a low budget solution...Is there a way to share a volume between multiple docker containers within EBS?

Without EBS I would just introduce a "Data Container" that is linked to every instance. This container holds all uploaded files...

But I don't think this would be possible to achieve within one EBS Application right?

Or is it possible to run multiple web containers and link them to one central container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spend the last view days moving all binary files to S3. Now the application is not storing any files locally which allows me to startup multiple instances of my web tier

Answer (score 0):

AWS has an Elastic File Storage (EFS) which can be attached to multiple EC2 instances. Its a network storage for sharing files, this can be used to have a persistent storage in an application, and is easier to use than attaching existing EBS volumes to single instance beanstalk enviroments.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html